# Permutation with prime order, fixed point

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Let $M$ be a finite set and $\varphi$ a permutation of this set with prime order $q$.
How do I show that $\varphi$ has a fixed point if $q$ is not a divisor of $|M|$?

Comment: What are the possible sizes of the orbits under $\varphi$?

Comment: The size of the orbit has to be a divisor of $|M|$.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Consider $\varphi \colon \{-1,0,1\} \to \{-1,0,1\};\; \varphi(x) = -x$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the action of the cyclic group $\langle \varphi \rangle$ on $M$. Since $\varphi$ has prime order $q$, every orbit under this action has either order $1$ or $q$. Thus if $q$ does not divide $|M|$, we can find an orbit of order $1$.

Comment: I think the contrapositive of your last statement is a bit clearer. If there are only orbits of size $q$ then since they are disjoint $|M|$ must be a multiple of $q$ as well.